# Moving the mouse causes events to not update

Tags: c++, sfml, keystroke

I've been working for the past two or so weeks on a for-fun project, a game. As of right now, I've just gotten to a point where the releases are stable, and there aren't any bugs. Except one. And it is very annoying - especially since I have no idea what is happening.

Essentially, I use SFML's isKeyPressed function to check if a key is pressed, and the Event::KeyPressed event to check for key releases.

**The bug is that if the player is moving (key is held down), and the user moves the mouse, and while the mouse is moving releases the key (key is no longer pressed), the player will continue moving, until something explicitly blocks him from doing so.**

This series of events is reproducible, so it shouldn't be my code, but rather, the way SFML processes events.

Does anyone know any good solutions to this problem?

(And somewhat related to this - if a user 'holds' the game window, the game freezes, and I'd really like that this didn't happen).

If any code is needed, or more details (Screenshots, etc), I'd be happy to provide. Thank you!

Comment: Please update your question to include a simple code sample which reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for key releases, you should use **Event::KeyReleased** event rather than **Event::KeyPressed**, don't you think ?

But while you use **isKeyPressed**, you shouldn't need to check for key release : just move the player on each frame that have your key pressed.